# While loop isn't closing when user inputs enter key?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a quick question and I couldn't find any information on it in the old posts.  It has to do with my while loop.  I want my while loop to end when the user inputs the enter key, i.e. when the patient ID is empty.  The while loop terminates if i hit enter for the first round of input, but if i input a lot of information and run the loop a few times hitting enter doesn't end the loop when it asks for patient ID again.  Here is the code.  I've tried many different variations for the while().  Thank you for the help!

```
    //Obtain Patient Id
    System.out.print("Enter patient: ");
    patientID= kb.next();

    //While patient id is not empty
    while(patientID.length()==0) {

    //  Obtain patient ID
    System.out.print("\nEnter patient: ");
    patientID=kb.next();

    //End While
```

Comment: Is kb a `Scanner` object? Then please post the code(s) which create it's instance for more information

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues. You need to use `nextLine()` to read a line. `next()` just reads a token.

```
patientID=kb.nextLine();
 //While patient id is not empty
while(patientID.length()!=0) {

//  Obtain patient ID
System.out.print("\nEnter patient: ");
patientID=kb.nextLine();

}
```

The while loop should also read "while patient ID is NOT empty". You'll need to set `patientID` to a non-empty value before the loop starts as I did here.

Comment: I fixed the issues with using next() and addressed the while issue, but when I ran it it terminated the while loop after one run automatically?

Comment: @TravisMiller Mh logic may be off. Try setting it back to `==`.

Comment: Hm when I set it to == it terminated once i input patient ID.  I did fiddle with it and reverted it back to != and changed the nextLine() back to next() on the inside while "enter patient ID" and it ran, but still wouldn't close when i hit enter on ID request.